# Is there a "unit" class? Would it be useful?

Tags: haskell, monoids, alternative-functor

Is there a class for types having a single unit value (not sure of the correct terminology here) i.e. types with some pre-defined *value*?

```
class Unit a where
    unit :: a

instance Unit () where
    unit = ()

instance Unit (Maybe a) where
    unit = Nothing
```

...for all Monoids, MonadPlus, etc.

I suppose another name for the class might be `Default`. This would have been useful twice recently now for me.

Probably unconvincing example:

```
extract :: (Unit r)=> Reader r a -> a
extract r = runReader r unit
```

Does this exist? Do others think it might be useful?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it would probably be useful. In fact, all of the slightly incompatible versions of it would be useful! Which is kinda the problem.

It's not clear what such a class would even mean, which makes it hard to actually use, because inevitably you'll hit types where there are multiple choices of a default value, and if it's not *immediately* clear which one the instance provides, you pretty much lose all benefit of having the class in the first place.

A few examples:

- For `Monoid` instances, you'd obviously expect the identity element to be the default. But now you're back to the problem of so many types having two or more sensible `Monoid` instances. Is the default `Integer` 0 or 1? For `Monoid`, the standard library uses `newtype` wrappers, but those are clumsy and make it difficult to work with the wrapped types--with `Monoid` it works okay because you get access to `mconcat` and such, but you can't *do* anything interesting with just a default value.
- For `Functor`-like types with an "empty" value, that gives an obvious default. This is what `MonadPlus` and `Alternative` are doing... and also overlaps with `Monoid`, and if memory serves me there's at least one type where those three instances aren't identical. Which do you pick, when there's more than one choice? Consider lists: You can blindly append them, giving an arbitrary `Monoid`, with the empty list as identity; but for lists of `Monoids` you can also `zipWith mappend`, giving a lifted monoid with `repeat mempty` as the identity. Many functors have analogous `Monoid` instances, but not always both--so whichever you pick for lists, you'll be conceptually inconsistent with some other `Functor`!
- For unit types like `()`, it's not hard to pick a default! But what about enumerations? Does it make sense to pick the first constructor? Sometimes, but not always. How will people using the class know?
- What about `Bounded`? If none of the above applies, you could use `minBound`. But some of the above types could be `Bounded` as well, so you'll confuse matters if their default isn't their minimum value.

Basically, there's just enough overlap that it *seems* to make sense... but really, you've got at least three different type classes in mind here, and trying to unify them is probably not as helpful as it seems at first.

---

If you can pin things down a little better and give a clear, consistent semantic interpretation of a "default" value, *without* just reinventing `Monoid` or another existing class, such that the type class is easy to use without having to stop and think about what "default" gets chosen, great! But I wouldn't get my hopes up on making it work.

That said, the one obviously sensible case that's not covered by any standard type class is singletons like `()`. Most of the time these aren't terribly useful--for obvious reasons!--which is probably why there isn't such a class. One place where such a class is *extremely* useful, though, is when you're doing something involving type-level shenanigans, because such a type represents a single value at both the type and term level--so a class for such types lets you manipulate type-level values freely, then conjure up the term that goes with it, so you can pass it to some other function that might, e.g., select a type class instance based on it. For that reason, I have [a class along those lines in my perpetually-incomplete type-hackery library](https://github.com/isomorphism/typewriter/blob/master/Data/Typewriter/Demote.hs), e.g.:

```
class TermProxy t where 
    term :: t

-- This makes explicit the lexical pun of () having type ().
instance TermProxy () where 
    term = ()

instance (TermProxy a, TermProxy b) => TermProxy (a, b) where 
    term = (term, term)
```

I doubt such a class is very useful in any other context, though.

Comment: Thanks for your generous answerto such a vague answer. I'm actually not at all interested in the notion of "defaults" (probably shouldn't have mentioned it!), but more in these ()-like things occuring on the left hand of a function (or abstractions there-of)... I need to think more about how I want to use this class. Thanks!

Comment: @jberryman: I think maybe what you're after is a type class for types with exactly one nullary constructor, then? Which would include `()`, `Nothing`, `[]`, etc., but not booleans or numbers or anything like that. That's at least clearly defined and not as trivial as the singletons alone.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. along the lines of my `Reader` example, I'm discovering that, for types that are sinks or functions or otherwise Cofunctor-ish, I can define interesting functions for the special case `()`., e.g. `liftCofunc :: (Cofunctor f)=> f () -> f a`. I thought it might be interesting to see if the function above could be defined more generally. Thanks again. *EDIT*: I guess it is probably not a coincidence that `Cofunctor` is also not a standard class ;)

Comment: @jberryman: Here's something to chew on, then--many covariant functors allow lifting products, e.g. `(f a, f b) -> f (a, b)`. Similarly, a contravariant functor may lift products to sums, e.g. `(f a, f b) -> f (Either a b)`. The identity for product types is the unit type `()`, and for sum types the empty type, often called `Void`. The only way to have something of type `f Void` is if `f` is a type with an "empty" value. So with covariance, `f ()` lets you get an `f a` with purely the information from `a`; with contravariance you can conjure an `f a` that discards the info from `a`. Duality!

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for some sort of `Default` type class.  While the semantics of what a "default" should be is debatable (and I suggest you accept C.A. McCanns answer for his valuable comments there), you can get a `Default` class from a fairly commonly used package called [`data-default`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default-0.3.0).

The class is:

```
-- | A class for types with a default value.
class Default a where
    -- | The default value for this type.
    def :: a
```

Comment: Thank you very much. as I commented to C.A. McCann, the notion of this being a "default" was sort of an after-thought and I'm going to have to have a good think about what I'm trying to do

Comment: Yeah, that `Default` class is about as consistent as you can hope for. It still has some of the inherent confusion I mentioned--for instance, some `Monad` instances are `return def`, while others aren't. So any function with a context like `(Monad m, Default m a) =>` is necessarily going to behave very differently for different `Monad`s.

Comment: I find `data-default` particularly useful for configuration structures and the like, that is, where a sensible default exists within the context of an application.  Plus then the instances aren't exported.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid a new class, you can define unit in terms of the Enum class:

```
unit :: Enum a => a
unit = toEnum 0
```

Or maybe better with the Bounded class:

```
unit :: Bounded a => a
unit = minBound
```

Both of these produce the expected result for the unit type (and most likely for any other single constructor type):

```
*Main> unit :: ()
()
```

The drawbacks compared to the data-default class (mentioned in another answer) is that there are fewer instances, particularly no instance that returns [] for [a]. Also the result is not what you might expect from some type, especially if you use minBound:

```
*Main> unit :: Int
-2147483648

*Main> unit :: Char
'\NUL'

*Main> unit :: Bool
False
```